# Return value of if/else condition, but also run code

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a newbie to Kotlin, but I freaking love it. There's a wonderful feeling when you can turn three lines of code into one. Now I often find myself looking at my code and thinking "there's some redundancy here. There should be a more concise way to do it." And when I do some searching, often Kotlin does provide a more succinct way.

Here's a problem where I FEEL there should be a simple, concise Kotlin solution, but am not aware of it. Hopefully you can enlighten me!

Take code like this contrived example:

```
fun doSomething(): Boolean {
    if (randomInt % 2 == 0) {
        foo = Foo()
        true
    } else {
        bar = null
        false
    }
}
```

Based on an `if` condition, I want to run some code and then return the value of the condition. It just bothers me that I have to explicitly say "if the condition is true, return `true`. If it is false, return `false`." It seems redundant. Of course, I could say `return randomInt % 2`, but I want to run code based on if it is true.

Is there a magic operator Kotlin has that I don't know about? Should I make a function to handle this situation for me, although the syntax of calling that would be different than an if statement? Is there some kind of mapping function, or some way to overload if? It seems like there should be a concise, clever answer, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: If you want to do this in 1 line only solution I know in Java is assignment inside if condition but in Kotlin assignment inside if, else and while doesn't supports.

Comment: Just stick to the solution of @pixel-elephant Not everything must be solved in a fancy new way just to not use good old if

Comment: I am sorry I down voted the question, but the motivation to find "a magic operator" to deal with dirty code is just so wrong.This particular case is solvable by extracting `randomInt % 2 == 0` into a variable, which is the same as you would do in Java, C and any other "old and boring" language. Kotlin is no magic, and kotlin code is only as good as we write it.

Comment: @voddan Thank you for explaining the downvote. I do not feel the downvote is justified, as asking "what's the best way to accomplish this programming task" is a perfectly legitimate question. I also disagree with the sentiments about "magic operators" and "dirty code". The whole reason Kotlin is so popular and a joy to work with is that it created new "magic operators" to reduce boilerplate and redundancy and make code more concise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I upvoted some of the answers. I should have considered splitting out the condition to a variable or having the true/false test after the condition.

But after sleeping on it, I have another solution.

New utility functions:

```
fun Boolean.onTrue(block: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    if (this) block()
    return this
}

fun Boolean.onFalse(block: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    if (!this) block()
    return this
}
```

And then my original code sample can be condensed to:

```
fun doSomething() = (randomInt % 2).onTrue { foo() }.onFalse { bar = null }
```

This is the most concise option, although it has its own disadvantages. Nothing prevents the user from, say, calling `onTrue()` twice or calling `onFalse()` before `onTrue()`. It looks quite different from a standard if/else, and if you use both paths, both `onTrue()` and `onFalse()` have to check the condition. And then, of course, there's remembering to use the new utility function instead of standard Kotlin operators. Still, it has an appealing brevity. I'll be interested to see what other people think.

Comment: It may seem like  a jerk move, but after consideration, I've gone with this approach. It's more concise, less redundant, more useful, more "Kotliny" I feel. It passes code review (although not without some dissent) and I've already found several cases where it shines. Much like Kotlin in general, I love how it simplifies my code.

Answer (score 7):

You can refactor your code a bit so that the return and code happen in different places:

```
fun doSomething(): Boolean {
    val isEven = randomInt % 2 == 0

    if (isEven) foo = Foo() else bar = null 

    return isEven
}
```

Comment: Call me an idiot, but I really don't get the other answers. Why would you overcomplicate returning `true` and `false` from an `if`?? This problem should not have existed in the first place, as demonstrated by this answer (which would work equally well in C and Java)

Answer (score 1):

You may explore some useful extension functions from Kotlin's [standard library](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt). For example, you may use `apply`:

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] with `this` value as its receiver and returns `this` value.
 */
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

Here, `randomInt % 2 == 0` will be the return value of `apply`.

```
fun doSomething(): Boolean = (randomInt % 2 == 0).apply { if (this) foo = Foo() else bar = null }
```

**Updates:** If you prefer a more readable code, it is not a good solution. Have fun :)

Comment: It's a good explanation but didn't solve the purpose. But deserve to upvote learn something new.

Comment: Horribly overcompliated.  The simple answer is store the result in a variable.  All this solution does is make your code less readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan The `boolean` acts as the receiver and the return value of the function and we use `this` to refer to the `boolean` within the lambda. Not so complicated at all. You may feel complicated because it is one-lined. Spliting it to multiple line of code may be more readable.

Comment: @BakaWaii No, I feel its too complicated because it replaces a simple boolean assignment with multiple levels of object creation and function calls.  Anyone who writes code like this is incompetent.  It takes longer to write, longer to understand, is not easy to understand by another maintainer, and provides no additional clarity or utility.  It's just bad.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I see what you are concerning about. Nice point :)

Comment: I would prefer [`<T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) over `apply` but even more I do not think is the right way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, you just have to get used to Kotlin's fantastic *stdlib* functions like `apply`, `with` and `let`. In this case, `apply` is what you need:

```
fun idiomatic(myInt: Int) = (myInt % 2 == 0).apply {
  if (this) println("is equal") else println("in not equal")
}
```

What happens: apply is invoked on `Any` object, a `Boolean` (the condition) in this case, which directly becomes the functions **receiver**, referred to as `this`. The important thing is, that `apply` will, after the supplied code block has been executed, return its receiver,  which is your `Boolean` here.

I hope this is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

@pixel-elephant's solution looks concise and good.

However, from the clean code perspective, your `doSomething()` function is doing two things.

If possible you can separate it out to two functions and move the if check to the topmost function:

```
if ( randomInt.isEven() ) {
    doSomethingEven()
    // ...
} else {
    doSomethingOdd()
    // ...
}
```